# Hudson - Clearcase plugin required

Tags: plugins, hudson, clearcase

I am trying to use Hudson for my project but the CC version I have is pretty old (Version 7.0.1.7).

I tried to integrate hudson with this CC but the plugin available is for newer version of CC and uses command arguments which are unknown to older version.

I am not able to find plugin compatible to this version of CC. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have the exact error message? I can then identify in the sources the incompatible command used and propose a patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the earlier plugins are available on the hudson site itself. Check the link below...

http://hudson-ci.org/downloads/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [ClearCase Hudson (now Jenkins) plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clearcase+Plugin), one solution would be to:

- identify what is incmpatible with a CC7.0.1 (for instance, if that plugin uses '`cleartool lsview -quick`' in order to get the list of views faster, this would not be compatible with CC7.0.x)
- recompile that plugin with a compatible command.
  The sources [are on GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin).